# How to get correct answer in for loop

Tags: python

I want to do multiplication using for loop. Here is the code.

```
a = 4
b = 6
for i in [a,b]:
    i*=2
```

The values of `a` and `b` remain the same. How to make it work?

Comment: `int` objects are immutable; you can't do what you are trying to do. Read  https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: What values do you want to multiply?

Comment: I would consider "map" with a lambda function. Or just define your own function f(x): return 2*x

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. If you only have 2 variables, `a*=2;b*=2` is definitely better. If you have a [variable number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164), you should use a list or dict and there should be easier ways (list comprehension, dict comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

`int` are immutable, so you'll need to rebind `a` and `b` to fresh int objects

```
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 6
>>> a, b = (i*2 for i in [a,b])
>>> a
8
>>> b
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary:

```
z = {'i': a, 'j': b}
for k in z.keys():
    z[k] *= 2
a = z['i']
b = z['j']
```